# Spinners con check box como elementos

Tags: android

Quiero implementar un spinner que contenga un arreglo de check boxes, he visto algunas aplicaciones que lo tienen pero no yo no lo he logrado. ¿Alguien sabe cómo realizarlo?

Comment: Ricardo, trata de implementar el ejemplo que te doy y preguntas duda, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es un MultiSpinner

```
package com.example.views;

public class MultiSpinner extends Spinner implements
        OnMultiChoiceClickListener, OnCancelListener {

    private List<String> items;
    private boolean[] selected;
    private String defaultText;
    private MultiSpinnerListener listener;

    public MultiSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MultiSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MultiSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)
            selected[which] = true;
        else
            selected[which] = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

        StringBuffer spinnerBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        boolean someUnselected = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (selected[i] == true) {
                spinnerBuffer.append(items.get(i));
                spinnerBuffer.append(", ");
            } else {
                someUnselected = true;
            }
        }
        String spinnerText;
        if (someUnselected) {
            spinnerText = spinnerBuffer.toString();
            if (spinnerText.length() > 2)
                spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length() - 2);
        } else {
            spinnerText = defaultText;
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                new String[] { spinnerText });
        setAdapter(adapter);
        listener.onItemsSelected(selected);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(
                items.toArray(new CharSequence[items.size()]), selected, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items, String allText,
            MultiSpinnerListener listener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.defaultText = allText;
        this.listener = listener;

        selected = new boolean[items.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++)
            selected[i] = true;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] { allText });
        setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public interface MultiSpinnerListener {
        public void onItemsSelected(boolean[] selected);
    }
}
```

Dentro de tu Layout agregarias la vista de esta forma (es important definitely el paquete para acceder correctente a la class MultiSpinner):

```
<com.example.views.MultiSpinner android:id="@+id/multi_spinner" />
```

Programaticamente usa el método setItems() para agregar tus elementos:

```
MultiSpinner multiSpinner = (MultiSpinner) findViewById(R.id.multi_spinner);
multiSpinner.setItems(items, getString(R.string.elementos), this);
```

La implementación de MultiSpinner es de David Vávra

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022474/250260